# Calling WebAPI from WebService?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services

I have this legacy code that is consumed by our partners which is an old webservice. I need to integrate some new functionality by adding a calling to an external WebAPI. When I try to create HttpClient in the cs file of the webservice it says the following

> The type or namespace name 'HttpClient' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'System.Net.Http' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Am I missing something in creating an instance of HttpClient in Webservice. I have added reference to System.Net.Http in my cs file.

UPDATE: This was my workaround. I have created a new 3.5 project, added files that are from my old project, converted it to 4.5 and added references to System.Net.Http and everything is fine now.

Comment: what is code in your .cs file?

Comment: @NicholasKing -- The code in the webservice is to fetch some data from database. I have to make a change so that I fetch some data from external WebAPI and merge it with the data from database before it is being returned for display.

Comment: Show enough of the code for us to reproduce the problem!

Answer (score 0):

The [System.Net.Http](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.aspx) library is only available in .NET 4.5 - which version are you running?

Alternatively, you can use [HttpRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.aspx) which is available in all versions.

Comment: @SubratoM have you actually added a reference to `System.Net.Http` to your project? It's a separate dll...

Comment: Yes I did. I have also added reference to System.Net.Http.Formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like [the HttpClient Class wass added in .Net 4.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx). Your old web service probably runs an older version of .Net. You might want to try to upgrade you service, and change it to .Net 4.5 if possible.

**Update:** Ok, so you have a .Net 4.5 project. Have you verified that you have added the correct references?

Note that including a reference to `System.Net` is not the same as adding one to `System.Net.Http`. The latter found under "***Extensions***" when adding references in Visual Studio (and not under ***Framework***, where the former is found).

**Update 2:** Try removing existing references to `System.Net.Http`, and adding the following NuGet package instead:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Net.Http
```

*(Ref: http://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Http and http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http)*

Comment: @SubratoM Ok, then you should find the library if you've included a references to it correctly. See my update.

Comment: Yes I did add it to the project from under extensions. (Actually I did this by going to Manage NuGet extensions and added Microsoft ASP.NET Web API Client Libraries. I have also installed Microsoft .NET Framework 4 HTTP Client Libraries).

Comment: @SubratoM Maybe those are not the correct references? See my 2. update. That works for me anyway...

Comment: What I did this time is created a new project as a 3.5 version, added my files compiled the project, converted it to 4.5, added references to System.Net.Http and now I am able to use HttpClient properly. This is strange and I am guessing upgrade didnt really work as it should have on my old project.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are referencing `System.Net.Http.dll` in .NET 4.5.

Try to add reference manually by right clicking on your project in Solution Explorer and click Add References when the dialog appears, select the leftmost tab  Scroll the list until you see an item called `System.Net.Http` double-click it and rebuild.

and make sure your project is targeting `.NET 4.5`.